inconsistent "Always Fit Window" behavior in VLC for two different videos
Two different videos:

both have same resolution (1920 x 1080)
one processed with Tencoder (frontend for FFMPEG), and the other processed with kdenlive (video editor that uses MLT framework)

The issue: they show up very differently in VLC.

One needs "Menu > Video > Always Fit Window" to be checked to fill the screen.
The other needs "Menu > Video > Always Fit Window" to be unchecked to fill the screen.


Video 1: processed using kdenlive (video editor that uses MLT framework) link:
How the file looks in the file system:

kdenlive project settings:

kdenlive render profile:

The MLT command looks like this in kdenlive (screenshot):

The MLT command in text form:
ab=160k acodec=aac channels=2 crf=23 f=matroska g=15 movflags=+faststart preset=veryfast real_time=-1 threads=0 vcodec=libx264
MediaInfo:

VLC with "Always Fit Window" checked: video underfills the screen:

VLC with "Always Fit Window" unchecked: video fills the screen:


Video 2: processed using Tencoder (frontend for FFMPEG) link:
How the file looks in the file system:

Tencoder encode settings:

MediaInfo:

VLC with "Always Fit Window" checked: video fills the screen:

VLC with "Always Fit Window" unchecked: video overfills the screen:


Summary:

despite the two videos having the same resolution (1920 * 1080)
to fill the screen, one video needs "Always Fit Window" unchecked and the other needs it checked.

Question for you dear reader: Why? (see Summary above).

This was fixed by doing the following in the project settings (via creating a new project profile):

Resolution - 1080x1920
Pixel aspect -  ratio 1:1
Display aspect - ratio 9:16

